# HTML dynamic table - multiple value text alignment issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I need to construct dynamic HTML tables using JavaScript where cells may have data about multiple fields, and things need to be aligned properly. I have created sample table below

[image]

In this example, first row's leftmost cell contains names of 3 countries(items), middle cell contains information about the country and right cell contains more comments on the item(country). I need to make sure that values in leftmost cell should be aligned according to how much space is taken up by data in middle and right cells. If Key column was moved to last, then name of country should display corresponding to Information for that country.

Similarly in 2nd row, there are no comments for Pizza, so comments for Burger should be aligned with key 'Burgers' and Information about Burgers rather than showing up on the top.

Below image shows incorrect alignment, right cell for row 1 contains population where capital/population data about countries is not aligned corresponding to that particular country.

[image]

Any advise on how to approach this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code, I guess nested tables would work.

Comment: The right way to complete the task would be putting all related fields in one row (no multiple values in cells), this will solve the problem. Best regards,

Comment: In which format are you getting the input data for populating the table?